# How to open specific topic from a chm file?

Tags: c#, chm

I have create chm file from chm processor software. By clicking on properties of particular topic I got htm link

htm link : mk:@MSITStore:D:\my.chm::/start.htm#_Toc417986991

But when I am trying to open from my c# app its giving error

c# code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(null, @"D:\my.chm", @"mk:@MSITStore:D:\my.chm::/start.htm#_Toc417986991");
```

When I am running my code and trying to open its giving error

> "This program cannot display the webpage"

Please help me to find solution of this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add a HelpProvider to your form and try something like the following code:

```
private const string sHTMLHelpFileName_ShowWithNavigationPane = "CHM-example_ShowWithNavigationPane.chm";    
private void btnHelpTopic2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
helpProvider1.HelpNamespace = Application.StartupPath + @"\" + sHTMLHelpFileName_ShowWithNavigationPane;
Help.ShowHelp(this, helpProvider1.HelpNamespace, @"start.htm");
}
```

The help CHM help file was added to the project in a subfolder e.g. \hlp. 
For download I provide a C# [VS2008 Project](http://www.help-info.de/files_download/CSharp2008_CHM.zip) including the code above and the help files with different help viewer windows (different CHM files for show case only).

Please think of #_Toc417986991 as a internal bookmark generated by CHM Processor Software.