# Chm file external links do not work on winform

Tags: c#, winforms, chm

When I opened my chm file with double click all external links are work. But when I opened my chm file via winform button click event, exteranl links does not work.
External links include some pdf files. I start chm as below;

```
pDokumantationCHMFile.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MANUEL\Example.chm";
pDokumantasyonCHMFile.Start();
```

What can be the reason of this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure but is this a typo in your Code sample?pDokumantasyonCHMFile.Start(); => pDokumantationCHMFile.Start();

Comment: Yes, I start chm with this way

Answer (score 0):

I think the linked file has a different location in your local developing Folder and the resulting release "\bin" folder. Please make sure all files (CHM and PDF) have the same place and are always publishes in your application release Folder.

If this may not help please have a look at a sample download mentioned in following thread:
[How to open specific topic from a chm file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456300/how-to-open-specific-topic-from-a-chm-file/32464708#32464708)

My way to do by Process.Start (only for example - this isn't the best way):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string helpFilePath = Application.StartupPath + @"\help-subfolder\C-Sharp-CHM-example.chm";
        // Verify if the file exists
        if (File.Exists(helpFilePath))
        {
            Process.Start(helpFilePath);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File not found [{0}]", helpFilePath));
        }
    }
```

The help file with some test links resides in a subfolder. Any place is possible for testing and I created a CHM file by myself for testing and don't have problems linking to PDF's. My Visual Studio 2015 Community is on a Windows 10 machine.

[image]

I remember of some 32/64 bit problems. Please see following link and note you need a target = _blank in the HTML link.

https://helpman.it-authoring.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=12508

Comment: Is folder place important? Because I don't use chm as an help. I start it like any program.

Comment: @tebdilikiyafet , please check the updated answer and give some more information about creating the CHM link and the use case in your application.